# How iconify xterm when it loses focus?

Tags: linux, xterm, slackware, fluxbox

I am attempting iconify a `xterm` terminal when it loses focus in `fluxbox`.

I am following this wiki:

http://fluxbox-wiki.org/index.php?title=Make_xterm_act_like_a_PC_game_console

And so far, I've got it appending this line

```
Control T : If {Matches (xterm)} {Delay {Iconify} 1}
```

to `~/.fluxbox/keys` file, which iconify the terminal when I press  **`Control T`** shortcut.

How can I get that behavior when xterm loses the focus?